# Solving a modular equation programmatically

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Consider that I've a mathematical equation of the form:
$$ (6+4\times x)\text{ } mod\text{ } 22 = 0 $$ 
How can I solve this modular equation by using a program, efficiently? By trial and error, one can infer that the answer is $x=4,15,26,...$. But how can I solve this programmatically?

I can not use a binary search here, as there is no pattern followed by numbers greater than the answer, and vice versa.( Plus, there are infinite solutions).

I can obviously check all values from $0,1,2,...,21$, but that wouldn't be efficient in my use case.

So, for a given equation of the form $$(a+b\times x)mod\text{ }m=0$$, is there any constant or logarithmic algorithm in $m$, that can be used to solve this equation?

P.S: I can't directly solve for $$a+bx=m$$. For example take $$(6+10\times x)mod\text{ }22=0$$
Here, $x=6$, is the correct answer which can't be inferred using the equation mentioned above.

Comment: Why not simply use [symbolic computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra)?

Comment: @dkaeae How does that help? And would it be efficient?

Comment: That's what the [big](https://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic.html) [math](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html) [toolboxes](https://reference.wolfram.com/languageoolb/tutorial/SymbolicComputation.html) do.

Comment: I can't use foreign math toolboxes, sorry if my question didn't clarify that. This is a subproblem of a competitive programming question, so all code must be, written by me, short and obviously, efficient.

Comment: You can't use them, but you might as well mimic them. There should be plenty of literature out there on the subject. And [NumPy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy) is even open-source.

Comment: This is essentially an exercise in modular arithmetic.